# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<name>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django

I am a beginner in learning code and am working on making a simple django site where users can write comments but I keep getting this error

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("profile/<str:name>/", views.profile, name="profile")
]
```

views.py

```
class NewPostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title")
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            author = request.user

            post = NewPost(title=title, description=description, author=author)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "network/index.html", {
                "form": form
            })

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "form": NewPostForm(),
        "posts": NewPost.objects.all()
    })
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class NewPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and my index.html

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'index' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form | crispy}}
            <button class="btn btn-primary"> Post </button>
        </form>
    </div>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body"> Title: {{post.title}} </div>
            <div class="card-body"> Description: {{post.description}}</div>
            <p> {{post.author.username}} </p>
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="{% url 'profile' post.author.username %}">
                    @{{post.author.username}}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I keep getting

NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the error is occurring with

```
<a href="{% url 'profile' post.author.username %}">
```

Make sure that each of these `posts` that you are looping through actually has an author and that each author has a username. Django won't be able to properly construct the url if `post.author.username` is `None`.

Comment: Answer describe all posts should have an author and all authors should have a username then the URLs works. If any case any of the blogs have not been authored or any authors haven't a username then not work.

Answer (score 1):

in this url : path("profile/str:name/", views.profile, name="profile")

do you have an view called profile?

and what does name in str:name refer to? username maybe? or author

you need to provide more details,

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have an project with author I faced the similar issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32426077)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check your admin panel if there is a post without author that's probably the problem

Answer (score 0):

**NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P[^/]+)/$']**

It's means something missing in database thats you are working for in loops .Django won't be able to properly construct the url  if somthing is blank. First go to the Django admit panel and find whats are missing.Example:Author,User,Admin etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a post **without** assigning a profile (owner) to it, you get this error. in other words, something that Django wants (in your database) **is blank**!

You must go to the admin panel and check all posts that are defined, None of them should be without an owner.